# Is there a way to modify text that is being changed by .innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I have a document (assignment, I guess) here asking for date and time. In the HTML document, there is a script tag in the body, where it gets the date, and a variable is set to it. So I have a blank paragraph with an id that is supposed to be changed by this, but I also have CSS for the paragraph. The problem is that the text won't align. Is it because the CSS is ignoring the javascript? I don't know. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
p.dat {
text-align: right;
}
</style>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" style="font: 24px 'Arial', sans-serif; position: absolute; right: 0;">Print-Friendly Version</button>
<br>
<p id="dat">
</p>
<br>
<p>
shorted to save time ^-^
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
var dateandtime = new Date();
document.getElementById("dat").innerHTML = dateandtime;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: should be `p#date` because `date` is `id`

Comment: The css won't ignore the javascript.

Comment: Oh, thank you, that fixed it